# Find and Replace alike extension in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I'm creating Visual Studio Extension and to implement one of its functionalities I need to perform advanced "Find and Replace" on the whole solution.
It could work the same as Find and Replace (Ctrl + Shift + F) in Visual Studio, but I want to call it by code.

I was doing research on this topic, but most of the answers are about the function in Visual Studio itself.
During my research, I have found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivsfindtarget.replace?view=visualstudiosdk-2019). But implementing this function seems like a tricky way to do this.

What is the best way to implement such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DTE.Find.FindReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.find.findreplace) API.